# How to send Data from HTML Form to Flash SWF?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, forms

I have an html form. I need to send its data to flash on submit button push.

We have this HTML form

```
<form>
First name:
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
<br />
Last name:
<input type="text" name="lastname" />
</form>
```

We want ON Form items values change to receive them in Flash app (Via JS for example)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you are planning to do?

Comment: needed Flash and JS code examples.

Comment: 1. use the example @dome points you to and strip out the bits you don't need, constantly testing. \n
2. make sure allowScriptAccess is set to "always" in both object and embed tags
3. make sure both object and embed use the same id/name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in adobe livedocs, I think it does what you need, to send data from js to a flash application using ExternalInterface, here some lines:

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return false;">
         <input type="text" name="input" value="" />
         <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendToActionScript(this.form.input.value);" /><br />
         <textarea cols="60" rows="20" name="output" readonly="true">Initializing...</textarea>
     </form>
```

source:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary